# itemize with enumitem: How can I set the font of the item's body without affecting the labels?

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I want the labels to be the same font/shape/size as the rest of the document. Only the item's body should be condensed. However, using the package's parameters like `font` doesn't allow me to specifically format only the item body.

[image: enumitem nomenclature]

Comment: You can change the font with the `before=` key, and thee label font with `labelfont=…`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, that helped me. Together with the ````font=...```` argument, I could achieve what I was looking for:

````\begin{itemize}[before=\fontseries{lc}\selectfont,font=\fontseries{lm}\selectfont]````

Comment: @Bernard Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @MulticolMetallurgist Could you add an MWE instead of the (unrelated?) image?

Comment: @schstandard: I followed your suggestion. Hope the example is illustrating the idea in a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, it is enough to change the font siize in the environment with the `before` key, and set the label font with the `font` key. Here is an illustrating example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}[before=\footnotesize, font=\large]
      \item \lipsum[10]
    \end{itemize}
     \lipsum[12]

    \end{document}
```

[image]